# Efficiently Parse Fields Using XQuery/XPath in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

I am attempting to parse out specific fields from XML files (plural) from a table in SQL Server. I have written a stored proc to do this using attribute-centric XQuery, but the efficiency is abysmal (3 hours for 31 rows). After some research I found that element-centric XQuery may be more efficient, but the only examples I've found so far have the XML file set to a scalar variable. In other words, one file that is copy-pasted into the query, then the fields are selected from T(C).nodes/node1/ etc.. I cannot use this approach as I am querying ~2 million records that each have their own XML file and the format/layout is not necessarily the same. The table also contains common SQL data types (varchar, int etc..)

Here's an XML example (each file for each ID is stored in the a table as a  file shortcut. Clicking on the shortcut opens the XML file in SQL Server as you would see below):

```
'<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3>
      <ID>555555555</ID>
    </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2a>
    <Name="John">
  </Node2a>
</Node1>'
```

Say for instance, I want to get the SUBMISSION_ID (varchar stored in the same table, but not in the XML file), name, and ID for all in the population that have some additional criteria. As I said, I have done this using the following attribute-centric approach:

```
    SELECT
       SUBSTRING(SUBMISSION_ID, 1, 20) as SUBMISSION_ID,
       SUBSTRING(XML_DATA.value('(//Node1/Node2/Node3/ID)[1]','varchar(20)'),1,9) as ID,
       SUBSTRING(XML_DATA.value('(//Node1/Node2a/Name)[1]','varchar(30)'),1,20) as Name
FROM dbname.dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE Name LIKE 'JOHN%'
```

Note: I'm using substrings because I am exporting the data to a tab-delimited text file, so I want fixed-length columns.

So my goal is to write this query more efficiently, maybe using element-centric XQuery, but I am not sure how I can set my XML format data as an array and parse fields from that array. I thought maybe I could use a cursor, but RBAR isn't necessarily the most efficient thing in the world either.

Here's an example of my second (and unsuccessful) attempt - using a cursor and element-centric XQuery:

```
DECLARE @Open_XML XML
        SET @Open_XML = 
   '<Node1>
      <Node2>
        <Node3>
          <ID>555555555</ID>
        </Node3>
      </Node2>
      <Node2a>
        <Name="John">
      </Node2a>
    </Node1>'
        ;

DECLARE XQ_Cur CURSOR STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT 
        tbl.SUBMISSION_ID,
        dbname.dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE.VALUE('ID[1]','varchar(20)') as ID,
        dbname.dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE.VALUE('Name[1]','varchar(20)') as Name,
        FROM dbname.dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE tbl, 
             @Open_XML.NODES('/Node1/Node2/Node3') dbname.dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE(XML_DATA),
             @Open_XML.NODES('/Node1/Node2a') dbname.dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE(XML_DATA) 

OPEN XQ_Cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM XQ_Cur 
WHILE 0 = @@FETCH_STATUS
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM XQ_Cur;
    END
    CLOSE XQ_Cur;
    DEALLOCATE XQ_Cur;
```

Comment: Are you allowed to add a column to your `dbo.EXAMPLE_TABLE` to hold the `Name`?  Your performance is bad because you are doing a table scan on a non-indexed, calculated column, for 2M rows.  If you can copy the `Name` data into another col, then you could index it.  Is that an option?

Comment: @tgolisch I see what you mean - I could add a column for Name, but the only problem is: how do I extract the names and insert them into the table? With that approach, I'm still scanning the table for un-indexed Names plus reading from and inserting into the same table. I believe that that would cause table lock.

Comment: Are you doing insert/update/delete via SP or raw SQL?  If it is SP, then you can populate/update the Name column within the SP.  If raw SQL, then you can use a trigger.  Triggers are not ideal, but they solve the problem.  For populating the empty rows (the first time), you could run a batch over night, using a cursor or simple update command.  Just don't apply the trigger until after the column has been populated the first time.

Comment: @tgolisch Thank you for the idea. Currently the stored procedure that I have written parses the fields from XML, inserts them into my tracking table (completely different table), then from that table, the data that were created on the current date are exported to a file(via bcp). This is a proc that runs on a weekly schedule and I don't want the same record exported more than once, thus the reason for the tracking table with created dates. I think your suggestion will still scan the table of un-indexed XML, do you have a different suggestion for XML parsing? I believe that's the root issue.